# Is it possible to radio between America and India?

Tags: ht, repeater

My friend and I want to see if we can Ham radio between San Jose, CA and Bangalore, India. We're beginners and are going to be using handheld radios. Are there any networks of repeaters, that could connect us, or could you suggest a resource to find them.

Comment: What band/frequency, what license class (US side)? While 10M FM repeaters do exist, license/frequency restrictions may affect availability. I suggest you edit the question with more specifics, for a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider whether the Internet Radio Linking Project ([IRLP](http://www.irlp.net/)) could eventually meet your goals.  There are currently a dozen or more IRLP nodes for the 2M, 70cm and higher bands in the San Jose, CA area.  However, there are currently no IRLP nodes listed as active in India according to the [www.irlp.net](http://www.irlp.net/) site.  It's possible that there is a country/region-specific regulatory issue that is preventing nodes in India.  If there is no regulatory roadblock then you and your friend could maybe be the ones to establish an IRLP node in Banglore and put India on the IRLP map.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to setup an allstar node in India, allstar link is really easy, and all you need is a computer, USB radio interface, and a radio (or a microphone and speaker). The USB radio interface runs for about 80 USD and any cheap computer capable of running Linux and has Ethernet works.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this would work would be to use a longer wavelength, 6M at the minimum, but more likely 15-20m. HTs don't come in that size.

As far as using repeaters, you might be able to find one that connects over the internet. I'm doubtful that such a thing exists, but it might.

Comment: There's both Echolink and IRLP (the Internet Repeater Link Project), although I'm not sure how active IRLP is these days. Either should work for what the OP is trying to do, but of course it wouldn't strictly be radio. For a radio-only solution, HF would be the way to go, but then you'd be hard pressed to do it with handheld radios.

Comment: The KQ2H repeater network http://www.repeaterbook.com/repeaters/FeatureSearch.php?system=KQ2H%20System&state_id=%&type=systems#sthash.LxjrBESK.dpbs does have a 10M repeater, linked to UHF, 220 and 900 repeaters. If within range, one could use a handheld on these bands to link with the 10M FM side. Technically, a US Tech level license could get 10M FM contacts even though he/she stayed within their licensed bands on their actual transmit. I can hear the UHF link on my HT, and Europe and SA come in well when 10M is happy.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered 10m FM. I've never used 10m FM before, I didn't realize it had that kind of power...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto this particular repeater is atop the Catskill mountains. I believe it is low power (<50W) but has a clear shot at the horizon. When the 10 meter band is "on" - the proverbial wet noodle can reach the world.